# How do I mount git repository to a docker container using gitlab ci?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I'm using dind, and I want to mount the git repo of the testing branch to a Docker container defined in a Dockerfile and a docker compose file.

I could git clone it again in the container but seems unnecessary and time waste if I can just mount it from the host.

I tried to mount it by putting the following code in the gitlab-ci.yml and docker-compose.yaml files but it's not working.

```
  volumes:
    # Mount the source code
    - .:/opt/repo:rw
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd normally expect you to build the code into the image and not mount it.  This would be doubly true in a CI setup where the `docker build` command isn't expensive and where you could `docker push` the built image (again, containing its code) to a registry.

Comment: You mean to `git clone` the repo again in the container?

Comment: You should be able to run the container without that volume mount and without having Git installed in the image; all of the source code should be built into the image already (in a CI system, from the branch that's being built).

Comment: so, you're saying that the source code its already in the container? because I can't find it.

Edit: I've seen the source code only in the container that builds the custom image but not in the custom image